# Is it possible the WPF events to be added to the queue for execution in sequence?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

If I add a button to the window and handle its click async event with a long process, it is possible to click multiple times a button even it is in progress. It keeps the events in the queue and executes them sequentially.

```
 private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Button 1 ends");
    }
```

The question: Is it possible to get like that result in sync form of event?

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Button 1 ends");
    }
```

We want to prevent multiple clicks when a user tries. If the system frozen or something went wrong, the user is able to click multiple times but we want to prevent this.

Comment: Easy wasy is to disable the button If you want user to prevent the button to be clicked when the existing method call is in progress,

Comment: No, it is the most deceptive way to do that. Because, as I mentioned above if the program gets stuck or something goes wrong it is possible to click multiple times before those preventions (disabling the element, using another bool variables, etc). I want to find a more accurate way to do that.

Comment: Use `((Button)sender).IsEnabled = false` in first line of click event handler. Good luck with clicking it twice.

Comment: How will you be able to click multiple times when you handle the exception correctly and disable the button?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: sorry I initially misunderstood the question thinking the requirement was to queue the clicks and prevent multiple simultaneous executions. Here is an update

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    button.IsEnabled = false;
    try
    {
        // Perform long task here
        
    }
    finally
    {
        button.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does _semaphore.Release(); mean Dispose(); ? Is it disposing with that command?

Comment: I don't think a semaphore will prevent clicking on the button another time, it will only prevent that the 'long task' will be executed while it's already running. Windows will still queue the click and execute it after the semaphore becomes released.

Comment: A lock mechanism is not at all required for this problem. Any type of lock mechanism intention is to avoid race condition.

Comment: No `Release()` is not the same as `Dispose()`. `Release()` will increase the current available count by 1. `Dispose()` will dispose of the object and you can't use it again.

Comment: Semaphore is basically restricting how many threads can access a piece of code. Multiple button click marked with async is not creating any thread. Async is a state machine pattern basically handling the control flow of the code execution. Only Task will create thread. The requirement is to just handle multiple UI clicks

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question, I thought the intent was to "queue the clicks" not prevent them from executing at same time.

Comment: Nothing to do with semaphore to queue the clicks as well as UI interactions are not creating threads.

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry for the confusion, I misunderstood the question initially.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a flag inside the semaphore?

```
// Initialize the Semaphore to initial and max count of 1
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    private bool alreadyExecuted = false;
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tmp = await functionToCall();
    }

    private async Task<bool> functionToCall()
    {
        // Wait for semaphone to have an available slot
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            if (!alreadyExecuted)
            {

                // Perform long task here
                // Only one handler can be here at a time. You can increase this by increasing max count and initial count of the semaphore in the constructor.
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            alreadyExecuted = true;

            // Release the lock in a finally block to ensure it is released even in case of an error
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
        return alreadyExecuted;
    }
```